# Swap css files before dom is ready as i dont want my page to flick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Head**

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>abc</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery-min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/service.js'></script>
</head>
```

**Problem**
I want to check even before the dom is ready to remove the css and dynamically add the css(whose filepath i get from json object).The problem why i have to do this is whil swapping the css files i can see the behaviour(like flicker) on my page. Ideas?

**Method inside service.js**

```
parse : function(data){
var fileName = data.css;
var styleFound = false;

$('link').each(function(){
    for(i=0; i<fileName.length;i++){
        if($(this).attr('href')=== fileName[i].file){
            styleFound = true;
            $(this).remove();
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
});

if(styleFound){
    for(i=0; i<fileName.length;i++){
         if (document.createStyleSheet)
             document.createStyleSheet(fileName[i].file);
         else {
                $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='"+fileName[i].file+"' />"));
        }
    }
}


     },

     };

       getService();
```

Comment: Under what condition are you swapping the css file?

Comment: @laymanje .on changing the language lets say from en to arabic the direction changes so i want to supply different stylesheet other than default one

Comment: Is the language being selected by the user, or by the server (IP location)?

Answer (score 1):

what you could do is something like this:

in your initial page, do not load any css at all, except for a little    file that says something like:

```
 /* hide everything */
    * {
       display: none;
    }
 /* show some sort of loader */
    #loader {
      display: block;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.8) url(image/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      ...
    }
```

As soon as you can, start inserting the links to the appropriate stylesheets in your header, with javascript

When all stylesheets are loaded, remove the link to the above stylesheet, and perhaps even the `#loader` div, again with javascript (smooth off course, and perhaps after a short minimum delay to prevent it from flashing by real quick)

It might not be perfect, but it will be clear to your users what's hapenning, and you won't get the flashing effect you have now. Returning users will never see the loader as things should go quick enough with the css files already in cache.

Big disadvantage of this technique is that non-javascript users will not see anything except for the loader however.

As a sidenote, personally I think this is something that should be handled by the server, wich should set the correct stylesheets in the header, based on the browser langauge locale or something...

Comment: Appreciate your help but what i am looking for changing css before body tags are excuted so i can switch to different css and doing that way wont give me any flicker or anything.. I tried so many things but i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You could load a css as  a text file and append it in a style tag. This would ensure that the file has been loaded before anything else.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: fileName[i].file,
    dataType: "text",
    async: true,
    success: function (data)
    {
        $("head").append("<style data-href='" + fileName[i].file + "'>" +  data + "</style>");
    }
});
```

And to remove this style tag,

```
$("style[data-href='" + fileName[i].file + "']").remove();
```

Or You can even disable a style sheet

```
$("style[data-href='" + fileName[i].file + "']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```